# Numpy: Adding different elements to an array

Tags: numpy

I have got an array like this(24 values).How can I add some elements before every single value in this array? I want to output an array(or just for the results printed) like  `1:80,  2:80,  3:80, 4:80 ..... 22:82.879, 23:80. 24:80 .`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` function and `dict` as:

```
arr = [24, 65, 83, 44]
idx = np.arange(len(arr))

new_arr = dict(zip(idx, arr))
new_arr

''' Output:
{0: 24, 1: 65, 2: 83, 3: 44}
'''
```

Comment: Thanks.But how to start from `1:` not from   ` 0: ` ?

Comment: Chnage the line as: idx = np.arange(len(arr))+1